# How to bridge an internal network interface to an OpenVPN tun/tap device

Tags: linux, iptables, vpn, bridge, iproute2

I'm using a two-VM setup wherein the first VM, `machine A`, has a closed, private LAN shared with the second VM, `machine B`, which has a second network interface that is configured to hit the internet.

Both adapters for the internal LAN are configured using static IPs; DHCP is disabled. The public LAN adapter (the second adapter in `machine B`) is confirmed to hit the internet successfully.

`machine A`'s adapter is configured to use the LAN address of `machine B` as its gateway address.

I'm trying to bridge the gap between the two interfaces on `machine B` with an OpenVPN connection, so that `machine A` *transparently* connects to the internet over this OpenVPN connection without needing VPN installed on the machine itself.

```
             (private LAN)
  machine A ─────────────────► ens34
                                │
                                ▼
             OpenVPN ────────►tun0 OR
                              tap0
                                │
             (public LAN)       ▼
     WAN ◄─────────────────── ens33
```

It makes no difference to me if the OpenVPN device is TUN or TAP. Whatever works is acceptable. It also doesn't matter to me if the WAN card is usable by `machine B` or if it's completely taken-over by the configuration - the OpenVPN connection is over a VPN service, not a private/enterprise network or the like; it's meant for all of the traffic to be routed through it, as a proxy.

It's worth mentioning that I also have a third interface on the machine, `ens38`, that is configured as host-only for SSH reasons, that will otherwise be down in all cases aside from debugging.

I intend for **all** traffic to be routed over the VPN connection - not just specific ports - and would rather have the network interface on `machine A` behave as closely as possible to how it would if the interface was configured to use a VPN connection directly.

I am creating the TUN/TAP devices via `openvpn --mktun --dev tun0`/`tap0` and then re-using them with `openvpn --config ... --dev tun0`/`tap0`.

---

I have confirmed the following, with no extra routing set up and empty iptables (as confirmed by an empty `iptables-save` output):

- `curl ifconfig.me` correctly routes through the WAN adapter, `ens33`, and shows my real IP.
- `curl --interface tun0 ifconfig.me` correctly routes through the VPN connection and shows the proxied IP address.
- Traffic is indeed reaching `machine B` from `machine A` at on the device `ens34`, as confirmed by `tcpdump`. ARP is correctly responding with physical addresses.
- `sysctl -p` returns `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1` (I have enabled `ip_forward` system-wide for all of the attempts below).

---

The first attempt was to use packet marking and iproute2 routes [as described in this thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/667270/linux-bridge-two-nics-and-route-traffic-through-vpn-tunnel-except-specific-dest), but there was nothing going through as per `tcpdump -i tun0`. My tables are `ACCEPT` by default so `-j LOG` was showing me less than ideal results for debugging.

---

The second attempt was to use pre-routing and masquerading using the following script:

```
#! /bin/bash
set -euo pipefail

IPTABLES=/sbin/iptables

WANIF='tun0'
LANIF='ens34'

# enable ip forwarding in the kernel
echo 'Enabling Kernel IP forwarding...'
/bin/echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

# flush rules and delete chains
echo 'Flushing rules and deleting existing chains...'
$IPTABLES -F
$IPTABLES -X
$IPTABLES -F -t nat
$IPTABLES -X -t nat

# enable masquerading to allow LAN internet access
echo 'Enabling IP Masquerading and other rules...'
$IPTABLES -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $LANIF -j MASQUERADE
$IPTABLES -A FORWARD -i $LANIF -o $WANIF -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -A FORWARD -i $WANIF -o $LANIF -j ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $WANIF -j MASQUERADE
$IPTABLES -A FORWARD -i $WANIF -o $LANIF -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -A FORWARD -i $LANIF -o $WANIF -j ACCEPT
```

This **did work** when setting the `WANIF` to `ens33` (the public WAN adapter) - `machine A` was **successfully** able to talk to the outside world through `machine B`, just not over VPN of course.

When using `WANIF=tun0` or `WANIF=tap0`, `tcpdump` showed no activity on those interfaces.

---

The third attempt was to use DNAT:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING --in-interface $LANIF -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.1.13
```

Where `10.8.1.13` was the IP of the TUN device at the time.

This did nothing.

---

The last attempt was to use a bridge adapter. I first tried with a TUN device but learned that bridge adapters didn't support them, so I switched to a TAP device and ran the following commands:

```
ip link add br0 type bridge
ip link set tap0 master br0
ip link set dev ens34 down
ip addr flush dev ens34
ip link set dev ens34 up
ip link set ens34 master br0
ip addr add 192.168.4.42 dev br0  # static IP otherwise configured for ens34
ip link set dev br0 up
```

This successfully resulted in traffic from `machine A` to reach the TAP device, but it was treating the VPN network as though it was a local peer and asking the VPN network ARP requests for public IPs (e.g. `Who has 8.8.4.4? Tell 192.168.4.80`).

---

I'm completely stumped. Is what I'm trying to do even possible? Why isn't iptables able to forward to TUN/TAP devices?

The second attempt (masquerading) seemed to be the best bet since it's what I perceive to be the 'proper' solution, but it seems that iptables simply refuses to route to the TUN or TAP devices.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/442760/cant-forward-traffic-from-eth-to-tun-tap but it was never answered, and the suggestions there are what are parroted all over the internet and simply do not work :/

Comment: Bridging VPN is always bad idea. Use routing.

Comment: @JiriB can you explain how? I have tried to use routes, as I explained above. They didn't work.

Comment: Sorry but it's not clear from huge pile info what you want to achieve. You have machine B as route/gw for your lan and this has a VPN tunnel to some machine on internet? And you want your LAN traffic goes over this VPN tunnel? It would be easier to state immediatelly in the beginning what you want to achieve instead of description of what you have done... If I was guessing correctly, then you need a to change default gw on machine A to go via IP on tun0 on machine B.

Comment: @JiriB I explained exactly what I want in the very beginning of the post. I have done exactly what you said - machine A has specified machine B as its gateway for the only NIC. The NIC on machine B that shares the LAN with machine A must have its packets forwarded over to the VPN adapter (and back, of course).

Comment: I did not say that 'machine A has (to have) specified machine B as its gateway', I said, machine A should have its GW IP of tun0 device which is not on same LAN.

Comment: @JiriB okay so I set the gateway of the windows NIC to the tun device's IP. Of course, this IP wasn't in the subnet, which windows warned me about. I checked `route print` and indeed it told me `dest: 0.0.0.0 mask: 0.0.0.0 gateway: <tun0 ip address> interface: <machine B's ip address>`, which seems correct. However, packets still aren't exiting the TUN interface (as confirmed by `tcpdump`). I've even added explicit `-j ACCEPT` iptables entries to make sure they weren't being dropped.

Answer (score 1):

The general rule about all of the similar setups is "you don't bridge l2 LAN segments with VPN". It causes more trouble than benefits.

Use the routing/forwarding.

This is the good advice that you will appreciate later; however, I fully understand that it has the enormous potential to attract the negative karma right now.

Comment: Okay, and how? I've attempted routing, as per a few of my attempts. Nothing works.